# How can we describe the attenuation of sound in an expanding gas cloud in a vacuum?

Tags: acoustics, vacuum, attenuation

For example, suppose a spaceship explodes. The sound of the explosion will travel in the expanding cloud of escaping gas. I gather that it should rapidly weaken and the pitch should drop, but I'd like to get more specific than that. Are there any models that suitably describe precisely this sort of situation?

Additionally, is it feasible for there to be a relatively safe distance away from such an exploding spaceship where the expanding gas cloud isn't yet extremely rarified and an audible sound might actually be heard through your space helmet?

Comment: You may want to look into the acoustics of rocket engines... they are controlled explosions that produce extremely high levels of "sound" followed by a highly controlled expansion process.